# Wordpress wp-super-cache not caching

Tags: wordpress

I don't know what else to check, I reinstalled wp-super-cache 0.9.7 following every line of the instrucions, activated by the admin page but nothing gets actually cached.

- I double checked .htaccess files in both document root and cache directory
- All directory permissions are granted to the webserver user
- WP_CACHE constant is defined to true
- PHP safe mode is disabled

What else can I do to finally get this plugin working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete advanced-cache.php file from wp-include